# PHP - Drop down list to display .txt contents

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, file-get-contents

I have a form that has a drop down list of song titles.  I want to be able to click on one of the song titles and the lyrics be loaded on the same page.   The lyrics are contained within .txt files in a folder called "Lyrics".

Example:

Drop down list contains:
Song1
Song2
Song3
etc.

When the user clicks on the song, the contents of the corresponding .txt file are displayed on that same page.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $song = intval( $_GET[ 'song_id' ] );
    $songs = array( 0 => NULL, 1 => 'Song1', 2 => 'Song2', 3 => 'Song3' );
    echo file_get_contents( $songs[ $song ] . '.txt' );
?>
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier using JQuery:

```
<a href="somefile.txt" class="link">Song 1</a>
<pre id="lyrics">
</pre>

<script>
$(function(){
   $('.link').click(function(){
     $.get(this.href,null,function(lyrics){
         $('#lyrics').html(lyrics);
         return false;
     });
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Good comment. Although he is asking for it in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of songs, and you use a simple naming convention then use that as a white-list to check the GET value is permitted before you even think of using

```
file_get_contents
```

```
    $song = $_GET['song'] ;
    $file = '/Lyrics/' . $song . '.txt' ; 
    $songs = array( 'help', 'she-loves-you', 'yellow-submarine' );

   // as a double check see if the file exists too

   if( in_array( $song, $songs ) && file_exists( $file ) ) {
       echo file_get_contents( $file );
    }
```

If you are smart you can also then reuse the same $songs array to create your drop-list.

< option value= yellow-submarine  > Yellow Submarine < / option>

And then if you keep this in a database, well you might decide that the 'slug' 'yellow-submarine' would make an ideal Private Key, but don't get me started on that ...

Answer (score -1):

This is quick solution, but highly insecure, use it only as example, how could be done, but shouldn't:

```
<?
```

// your page code here
// this is body where you want to put song lyrics

```
file_get_contents($_GET['songName'].".txt")
```

// else..

```
?>
```

in meniu:

```
<a href="songs.php?songName=song1">song1</a>
```